# Printing a C++ LPCWSTR to a file

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to print an LPCWSTR value to a file, but it only prints the address, not the value.

I've tried dereferencing the variable (using *) to get the value , but this doesn't work either.

How can I print the value ?

```
void dump(LPCWSTR text){

  ofstream myfile("C:\\myfile.txt", ios::app );
  myfile << text << endl;
  myfile.close();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wofstream` (basic_ofstream). The reason this will work is because the `w` versions of the std streams are designed to work with wide character strings and data. The narrow version you are using will see a wide string which probably contains some embedded nulls and will think it is the end of the string.

Comment: The reason the "narrow" version does not work is because there is no operator<<(ostream, wchar_t*). There is operator<<(ostream, void*) though, and this is what gets selected in this case.

Answer (score 1):

wofstream will generate an output that is also unicode (without a BOM).  That may not be what Brian wants.

Unfortunately if you want your file to be 8 bit characters, you're going to step out of C++ strings and convert the unicode strings into 8 bit characters.

You can use [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be(VS.80).aspx) to convert the string to 8 bit characters.  The conversion is done in the current locale, so make sure you use [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d(VS.80).aspx) to ensure that your conversion happens in the correct locale.  Unfortunately the documentation for setlocale indicates that it won't work to convert to UTF-8 :(

Comment: Assuming that by "output" you mean "what gets written to the file": It is inaccurate to say that wofstream will generate Unicode output. What it outputs depends on the imbued locale (the codecvt facet, more precisely) of the filebuf.

Comment: It is also inaccurate to say that an external conversion is needed to get "8 bit characters" to the file. wofstream *does* write bytes to the file, not wchar_ts: it's filebuf performs the wchar_t->char conversion using the locale's codecvt facet.